# Can I download the add-in from Microsoft Seller Dashboard?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, seller-dashboard

I have submitted a SharePoint Hosted Add-in to Microsoft Seller Dashboard (SharePoint Online).

Unfortunately, I lost my source codes and published file together.

Now, my add-in is rejected for some reason. And now I want to modify the add-in and resubmit it.

But I not having source code and published app file.

Also I am not able to see any download option available in Microsoft Seller Dashboard.

So, I want to know whether is there any way so that I can get the *.app file from Microsoft Seller Dashboard, so that I can get my source code back after unpacking the *.app file?